# How to find 2 Assignment operator in regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to find 2 symbols together "+*" , "-/", or such and also I want to identify if it's  "3-", "4-" "*4" and such. I will be looking for it inside and array or strings like such ["2" , "+", "3","/" , "2"]

Comment: I don't understand your question but I gave it a shot. Please let me know if I had the right idea.

Comment: You should really ask better questions. What's the common theme of "3-", "4-" "*4" etc.. It's also generally appreciated if you try it yourself and show where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to match a symbol followed by a number or a number followed by a symbol

the regex would look something like this

```
/^[+-\/\*]\d$|^\d[+-\/\*]$/
```

Breakdown

`^` - Start of line

`[+-\/\*]` - Any one of the symbols. Asterisk and forward slash must be escaped

`\d` - Matches any digit (0 through 9)

`$` - End of line

`|` - Or

`^\d[+-\/\*]$` - starts with a digit and ends with a symbol.

Please let me know if this is what you are looking for. Otherwise I can fix this.

In Ruby, let's pretend you have an array as follows

```
array = ["2" , "+", "3","/" , "2"]
```

You can find if any two consecutive elements match the above pattern as follows

```
array.each_cons(2).to_a.any? { |combo| combo.join.match(/^[+-\/\*]\d$|^\d[+-\/\*]$/) }
```

Breakdown

1. Use the `each_cons(2)` function to find every two consecutive characters in the array
2. use the `any?` method to find if any elements in the array satisfy a condition
3. Iterate over every element and find if any of the two joined together match the regex pattern

Comment: Thank you. Let's say I have an array ["2", "+", "3", "+-", "-3"]. I want to identify the last two items in the array.

Comment: Thank you again, but I don't know what's in the array yet. I need to able to find if some strings are in that format inside my array.

Comment: Check the last part of my answer. It will return true or false if any strings match the format

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to upvote and accept this post if you found it helpful

Comment: Sure! I accepted your post but don't yet have enough reputation to upvote. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the second part about "3-" etc. But the basic idea for the rest is:

```
your_array.each do |element|
  result element.match([/\+\/-]{2}/)
end
```

Note that the following characters have to be escaped with a backslash when used in ruby:

```
. | ( ) [ ] { } + \ ^ $ * ?.
```